# Reading different data types from a txt file in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner, txt

I have a text file that has data of various kinds such as int, String, and (String)ArrayList element. This data has to be passed into the constructor of an object as a parameter however, I am having trouble separating the ArrayList from the txt file.

The ArrayList can be of size "n" and should be passed into the constructor as an ArrayList.

The data in the txt file is divided as follows:-

```
int, String, int, ArrayListElement; ArrayListElement, int.
```

As you can see, the elements of the ArrayList are separated by a semicolon meanwhile the other elements are separated by a comma.

The constructor takes in its parameters as follows:-

```
Constructor(int, String, int, ArrayList, int);
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: by writing a mapper who maps your input to those types

Comment: It would be clearer to see some of this text file. It sounds like you don't have an ArrayList object yet though. Only text to parse.

Comment: @Stultuske Do you mean a hash map?

Comment: The text file does not exist yet

Comment: Yeah it's only text, there is no arraylist in the txt, you have to create it

Comment: @NBG no. how do you get to hashmap? do you know what a Mapper is? not a Map, a Mapper.

Comment: @Stultuske oh alright

Comment: Have you tried to write some code to solve this already? If so, could you add it to the question?